# How do I read the response body as stream with Dio in Dart?

Tags: dart, dio

I have an implementation of event-driven parsing of XML as in the method below:

```dart
  @override
  Stream<XmlNode> streamItems(String feedUrl) async* {
    final uri = Uri.parse(feedUrl);
    final req = await HttpClient().getUrl(uri);
    final res = await req.close();

    yield* res
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .toXmlEvents()
        .normalizeEvents()
        .selectSubtreeEvents((tag) => tag.name == 'item')
        .toXmlNodes()
        .expand((element) => element);
  }
```

XML parsing is not the important part, but in order to use `toXmlEvents`, I need to have `Stream<String>` as documented [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/xml/latest/xml_events/XmlEventDecoderExtension/toXmlEvents.html).

The documentation for it only uses built-in `HttpClient`, which I initialize in the body. The problem is, I extensively use this method in the app. For every XML request, it continuously initializes `HttpClient` instance. It's not desirable.

I have `Dio` instance injected into the class, and the caching is already set up. I'd like to use it, but I couldn't find a way to read `response.data` as a `Stream<String>`. Is there a way to read a simple GET request as `Stream` with Dio.

Thanks in advance.